# Autenticação bearer Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

Galera, sou iniciante em xamarin e tenho uma duvida quanto autenticação em uma API, quando estou consumindo via C# ou angularJS por exemplo consigo informar na url o tipo de autenticação (token que salvo em uma sessão) que obtive no bearer.
No Xamarin forms não entendi ao certo como eu faria isso, pois tentei criar com sesson e mesmo assim não funcionou, já até busquei videos no youTube e não encontrei sobre, posso estar procurando da maneira errada e minha duvida pode até parecer ridícula para quem já manja, mas..
não estou mesmo conseguindo fazer isso, alguém pode ajudar como posso fazer para consumir uma API e autenticar as chamadas get com autenticação ?

Answer (score 2):

É necessário salvar o `token` localmente, no caso do Android, isso se chama `SharedPreferences`, segue um exemplo de como faço nas minhas aplicações.

Primeiro eu crio uma pasta **Helpers** no projeto `PCL` e dentro crio uma classe estática chamada `Settings`:

```
public static class Settings
{
    private static ISettings AppSettings
    {
        get
        {
            return CrossSettings.Current;
        }
    }

    #region Setting Constants

    private const string SETTINGS_USERNAME_KEY = "UserName";
    private const string SETTINGS_EMAIL_KEY = "Email";
    private const string SETTINGS_TOKEN_KEY = "access_token";
    private const string SETTINGS_NICK_NAME_KEY = "NickName";
    private static readonly string SETTINGS_DEFAULT = string.Empty;

    #endregion

    public static string UserNameSettings
    {
        get
        {
            return AppSettings.GetValueOrDefault(SETTINGS_USERNAME_KEY, SETTINGS_DEFAULT);
        }
        set
        {
            AppSettings.AddOrUpdateValue(SETTINGS_USERNAME_KEY, value);
        }
    }

    public static string UserNickNameSettings
    {
        get
        {
            return AppSettings.GetValueOrDefault(SETTINGS_NICK_NAME_KEY, SETTINGS_DEFAULT);
        }
        set
        {
            AppSettings.AddOrUpdateValue(SETTINGS_NICK_NAME_KEY, value);
        }
    }

    public static string EmailSettings
    {
        get
        {
            return AppSettings.GetValueOrDefault(SETTINGS_EMAIL_KEY, SETTINGS_DEFAULT);
        }
        set
        {
            AppSettings.AddOrUpdateValue(SETTINGS_EMAIL_KEY, value);
        }
    }

    public static string TokenSettings
    {
        get
        {
            return AppSettings.GetValueOrDefault(SETTINGS_TOKEN_KEY, SETTINGS_DEFAULT);
        }
        set
        {
            AppSettings.AddOrUpdateValue(SETTINGS_TOKEN_KEY, $"Bearer {value}");
        }
    }
}
```

Após isso, no meu método de login eu atribuo os valores aos campos:

```
public void MeuMetodoDeLogin(){
    Settings.TokenSettings = "Token Bearer";
    Settings.UserNameSettings = "Nome do usuário";
    Settings.UserNickNameSettings = "NickName";
    Settings.EmailSettings = "Email";
}
```

Depois, para fazer as requisições eu utilizo o pacote do `nuget` `RestSharp`, com ele eu crio métodos genéricos onde preciso passar apenas as URL's que quero fazer a requisição. Nesses métodos eu chamo o `Settings.TokenSettings` que contém o `token` do usuário ;

```
public class BaseService
{
    protected RestRequest _request;
    protected RestClient _client;
    protected readonly string _urlBase = "http://MyUrl.com.br:1234/api/";

    public virtual async Task<List<TEntity>> GetAllAsync<TEntity>(string url)
    {
        try
        {
            _client = new RestClient(_urlBase);
            _request = new RestRequest(url, Method.GET);
            _request.AddHeader("Authorization", Settings.TokenSettings);
            _request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            IRestResponse<List<TEntity>> resposta = await _client.ExecuteTaskAsync<List<TEntity>>(_request);
            var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TEntity>>(resposta.Content);
            return obj ?? new List<TEntity>();
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {

            return new List<TEntity>();
        }

    }

    public virtual async Task<List<TEntity>> GetAllByIdAsync<TEntity>(int id, string url)
    {
        try
        {
            _client = new RestClient(_urlBase);
            _request = new RestRequest(url, Method.GET);
            _request.AddHeader("Authorization", Settings.TokenSettings);
            _request.AddParameter("id", id);
            _request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            IRestResponse<List<TEntity>> resposta = await _client.ExecuteTaskAsync<List<TEntity>>(_request);
            var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TEntity>>(resposta.Content);
            return obj ?? new List<TEntity>();
        }
        catch (System.Exception)
        {
            return new List<TEntity>();
        }

    }

    public virtual async Task<TEntity> GetByIdAsync<TEntity>(int id, string url)
    {
        try
        {
            _client = new RestClient(_urlBase);
            _request = new RestRequest(url, Method.GET);
            _request.AddHeader("Authorization", Settings.TokenSettings);
            _request.AddParameter("id", id);
            _request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            IRestResponse response = await _client.ExecuteTaskAsync(_request);
            var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TEntity>(response.Content);
            if (obj == null)
                return default(TEntity);
            else
                return obj;
        }
        catch (System.Exception)
        {

            return default(TEntity);
        }

    }

    public virtual async Task<TEntity> GetAsync<TEntity>(string url)
    {
        try
        {
            _client = new RestClient(_urlBase);
            _request = new RestRequest(url, Method.GET);
            _request.AddHeader("Authorization", Settings.TokenSettings);
            _request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            IRestResponse response = await _client.ExecuteTaskAsync(_request);
            var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TEntity>(response.Content);
            if (obj == null)
                return default(TEntity);
            else
                return obj;
        }
        catch (System.Exception)
        {

            return default(TEntity);
        }

    }
}
```

Por fim, para chamar o método será necessário instanciar a classe `BaseService` e chamar o 1 dos métodos:

```
List<MinhaClasse> minhasClasses = GetAllAsync<MinhaClasse>("GetMinhaUrl/");
```

Comment: eu iria dizer o mesmo rs